# Is it a good idea to save BuildContext in a varible as a class instance?

Tags: flutter

Is this a good idea?

```dart
  // Maybe save the context here?
  // BuildContext _ctx;

  Widget _buildItem() {
    // No context here!!!
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // we have the context here
    final dataList = getDataList(context);
    return ListView(
      children: dataList.map(_buildItem).toList(),
    ); 
  }
```

Update: I just find the `Builder` widget.  Is this a good use case?

Comment: For which purpose `_ctx` will be used ?

Comment: @dm_tr The idea was `_ctx = context` in the `build` function  so that `_buildItem` can use `_ctx` to access `context`.

Comment: You dont need to reinvent the wheels for that. Just add context parameter to your method like this `Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context)`. Then when calling it in build method, context it directly passed

Comment: What is the contentType of `dataList` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice save the context in a variable. Always search for an alternative solution when you need the context.
Furthermore when you have to create a custom widget, create a new class that extends a Stateless widget instead of using a function. If you come from react, here there arent hooks, so it might be troublesome to update your widget in future. Using classes is the proper way to create custom components and has various advantages like performances, widget inspector, etc.

If you can't renounce to functional declaration here there's an interesting article:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/use-functional-widgets-in-flutter-to-reduce-boilerplate-code-9e815c2ddb94

Comment: Why would classes help performance in this case?

Comment: When dealing with a big application sometime you need to update the state of a single component instead of re-rendering an entire page. When you use functional components you can't update their content without re-rendering also the parent component, causing small to big performance loss. That's why you use a class or the library that I suggest you above in the article

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the `context` anywhere, even outside your `build` method, you can for instance use [Get package](https://pub.dev/packages/get) which hold the context of your app no matter the place. Each time you need the `context`, just do it as simple as `Get.context`